# impossible to save source code in wysiwyg blocks if <a> does not contains some strings

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

It is impossible to use an icon as anchor  in wysiwyg blocks.

```
<a href="https://myfburl"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f "></i></a>
```

The content is lost when editing back a block

it only works for strings

```
 <a href="https://myfburl">some text</a>
```

Comment: You're not closing the `<a>`

Comment: u are right but this also <ul class="rs">
<li>
<a aria-label="lien Facebook" title="Facebook" href="https://myfburl/">
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f ">
</i>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: is this not valid?

Comment: to be more precise the module is wysiwyg and not ckeditor

Comment: Maybe you didn't allow `<i>` in your text format settings under allowed tags?

Comment: Please share more info, what is your text format, and what is the text filters that are used?

Comment: after a more thorough look , it is the absence of text inside the <a> that causes problem, even if all text format filters are opt-out. Is it really something that is wished? not allowing icons or images to be used as anchor?

Answer (score 0):

If this only happens when a `Text format` is associated with a `WYSIWYG profile`, regardless of the format's `Text filters` or the `Editor` assigned to it, then try using a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) as the anchor text:

```
<a href="https://myfburl"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f "></i>&nbsp;</a>
```